# How can I make my system open my Mac Discord *app* (not Chrome) to the correct place in a discussion whenever I click a Discord URL?

Tags: applications, google-chrome, links

I use the Discord app on Mac.

If I click a Discord URL such as https://discord.com/channels/828768337978195969/906115083250307103/938148914362728539 (in a text file or a Google Doc or on a web page), it just opens in Chrome.

How can I make my system open my Discord *app* to the correct place in a discussion whenever I click a Discord URL?

(I don't want to browse Discord in the browser; I only want to use the Mac app.)

P.S. I've already asked Discord's support team, and they instructed me to [completely uninstall and reinstall](https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/360022082931--macOS-Install-and-Updating-Errors) the Discord app, which didn't help.

Comment: I'm not sure as you can. The URL might point to `discord.com`, but the protocol the URL calls is `http`… changing your handler for `http` will mean *everything* will try to open in Discord instead of a browser.

Comment: you can set automatic redirect from chrome to discord with https://add0n.com/open-in.html